# Best HTML (with CSS-3 styles inside header) Compression/Obfuscating

Tags: compression, css, obfuscation

I have an HTML structure which has css3 inside e.g. @-webkit-keyframes,..etc

Is there any good compression/obfuscating method/tool (online or not) which could minify all that code and would also be good if it would be hardly readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/). Use it with an automated build tool such as [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and it's quite powerful. I recommend you check our this blog on [Building Web Applications with Apache Ant](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/09/16/). Should have all the minifying, compressing goodness you need.

Comment: thanks, but at first it seemed a little complicated because of the needed components, so i found an online YUI compressor because i only needed to compress the CSS. Basically what i really would like to have now is an css obfuscator that could rename all class names and id's inside my html & css. Would you know any way?

Comment: Johua, I think minifying CSS is a great idea. Obfuscating it is a terrible idea. If you change all your class names to arbitrary symbols, it would be a huge pain to debug css issues because nothing would be named in a readable manner. The handful of bytes you'd save by making "author" into "a" would not be worth the pain.